# Plural identifying fields in Relay also for non-root fieds

Tags: relayjs, relay

Plural identifying fields are [described](https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/objectidentification.htm#sec-Plural-identifying-root-fields) only for root fields.

Is possible to use them also for non-root fields? I know that generally I can use fields with arguments - but in some case it would be useful to have this 'identifying' mode where argument is array and result is list of corresponding nodes.

And I understand that I can already do that - question is more if Relay supports it. So it would know that I am providing individual ids (or some other keys).

As example if I query

`project (ids: [1,2]) { name }`

and after that I change it to

`project (ids: [1,3]) { name }`

I would expect that relay just fetches the project with id `3`